# Create new User with Completely different workspace from the others

Tags: permissions, users, workspaces, user-management, adduser

I have just one user(For example User_One the name) and a root on my system and i want to create a second user (For example User_two the name) who I want him to have :

*His own desktop with his own apps that User_One can NOT see or use ,same goes the other way User_two can not use or see user_one apps or data generally (if possible)

*If possible make him invisible on the start up screen, what I mean is when you boot up ubuntu do not show User_two on the list of available users to log in, instead I manually have to type the name and password to log in as him

Any idea,video,piece of code or advice will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the steps to achieve this:

1. **Stop user_two from appearing in login screen:** Create a file in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users` called `user_two` and add the following lines `(sudo nano /var/lib/AccountsService/users/user_two)`:

   ```
   [User]
   SystemAccount=true
   ```
2. **Prevent each from accessing each others home directory:** Then modify the folder permissions on user_one so user_two can access the former's home directory and vice versa:

   ```
   sudo chmod 750 /home/user_one
   sudo chmod 750 /home/user_two
   ```

Note: This is a manual method for the home directory permissions configuration, you can modify the `/etc/login.defs` to always create this permission whenever a new user is created by the admin(s). In that file change the line:

```
UMASK     022
```

to

```
UMASK      027
```

From hence forth a new user's home directory will have the permission of `750` at creation.

Comment: It worked thank you for the help!